# UK Government Debt Statistics

Tags: fixed-income, finance, central-banking

I would like to find some stats regarding UK Government debt. Any leads ?

I am looking for following questions

1. Debt / GBP ? ( Got it already )
2. Debt profile ( by maturity, instrument)
3. New debt issuance calendar ( how much monthly / annual)
4. QE ( how much monthly ? what do they buy ?

Comment: Did you check https://www.dmo.gov.uk/

Comment: I actually did found quiet a bit expect the Question 2/3

Comment: Debt in GBP or debt to GDP? Not sure if Q1 has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

*New debt issuance calendar ( how much monthly / annual)*

https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/pdfdatareport?reportCode=D5J

"This calendar includes all the key operational dates including gilt auction dates, the dates when auction sizes (and for new gilts the coupon) are announced and major redemptions. It also includes dates associated with the implementation of the remit e.g. quarterly consultation meetings, dates of quarterly gilt auction (and Treasury bill) issuance calendar announcements, and, when known, the dates of the Budget and Spring Statement."

EDIT: for your question 4, see the "market notices" section of the BoE site. E.g. for the current month (Feb 2021), https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/markets/market-notices/2021/february/asset-purchase-facility-gilt-purchases-february-2021. Has info on what maturities they plan to buy, in what quantities, and on which dates/times.

Comment: It's 2021 and their choice of format is still Excel and Word. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

For macroeconomic aggregates, I recommend the FRED database which is managed by the US Fed but includes economic and demographic statistics for other countries as well, with OECD and IMF being the primary source of country-level data.

1. [Debt to GDP](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DEBTTLGBA188A)
2. [Gov't Debt Outstanding, All Maturities](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/TDSAMRIAOAIGB)

etc.